# Unwanted LastName sort, although there is no command for it

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.NET, I have this Eval below and I'm using EntityFW.

When I pull LastName from Northwind, the data is sorted alphabetically,

when I pull FirstName, the data is sorted by EmployeeID.

Why is that? (I don't change any command between cases)

Screenshot of comparison: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTpTc.png**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Urunler" OnItemCommand="Urunler_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("LastName")%></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

```
NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Urunler.DataSource = db.Employees.Select(emp => new
        {
            emp.LastName,
        }).ToList();
        Urunler.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you order at all if it matters?

Comment: @TimSchelter I can do that, however I want to know the reason why this happens

Comment: Well as you saw, it depends on the columns you select. Try running a `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table` without `ORDER BY` and swapping the column order. Depending on the data type and applied indexes, the resultset is ordered differently. If you want to sort, do so explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an idea, but you may have an index on `LastName` column, so that when you query on this column in comes "naturally" sorted. If you don't have index on `FirstName` it comes out sorted on the primary key, wich is usually the clustered index.